# Adding CSS to a Javascript Widget

Tags: javascript, css

I am developing a Javascript widget for other websites to consume. I have 2 javascripts and one php file. One Javascript for user to consume and other to make a JSON request and the php to digg the data. Things are working great and data is being displayed, as well.

Now I need to add CSS to the widget. I don't want the users to code the CSS in their side. How do I do it? Do I need code all inline css? or Append a css file in the javascript?

I know this is very basic. But, I am not familiar with this stuff. So, if you guys point me to the right direction that would be great. I need the sample code as well.  I checked many site. They simply have the javascript code.

Thanks!

```
    End user Javascript
------------------------

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/userwidget.js"></script>
<div id="results">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
ajax_get_my_data();
</script>

AJAX Javascripit
----------------

function ajax_get_my_data(){
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "http://mydomain.com/widgets/userwidgetcore.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            results.innerHTML = "";
            for(var obj in data){
                results.innerHTML += data[obj].propertyA;
            }
        }
    }
    hr.send("var1=stock&var2=up");
    results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}


PHP code
------------

<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
...........
Databse logic
.......

         $_out = '<table id=\"rounded-corner\">';
         $_out .= '<thead>';
         $_out .= '<tr>';
         $_out .= '<th colspan=\"3\" scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded-q6\">Stocks Under Accumulation</th>';
         $_out .= '</tr>';      
         $_out .= '<tr>';
     $_out .= '<th scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded-q5\">Ticker</th>';
         $_out .= '<th scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded-q5\">Price % Change</th>'; 
         $_out .= '<th scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded-q5\">Volume % Change</th>'; 
     $_out .= '</tr>';
        $_out .= '</thead>';
    $_out .= '<tbody>';

  ..............  
 ..................
$jsonData = $_out;
echo $jsonData;
?>
```

now I need to load the css to the tags. How do I do it?

Comment: Well why not simply adding a .css file ?

Comment: Inline CSS is your best option. Look at the Twitter widget as an example.

Comment: No. Inline CSS is NOT your best option. It's not reusable, and hard to maintain/update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could append it to the head of the page via javascript

```
var fileref=document.createElement("link");
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  fileref.setAttribute("href", "filename.css");
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Comment: Should part of the 2nd widget ? the one makes the AJAX call?

Comment: im not sure as you didnt post any code, im guessing it should be in the part that the user includes on their page for widget to work

Comment: I added my code in the question now. It may give you better idea of..what i am into?

Comment: add it to userwidget.js

Comment: Not working for me. I modified the code and placed in the wordpress site widget. Didn't pick up the css.

Comment: As this is an external site, the css element itself not found anywhere in the doc. The data is rendered from 1st script. I saw this example http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml. But the demo table is already coded in the main document, itself.

Comment: This worked. There was some minor mistake in my other part of the code. You can see the styled widget in the right hand side bar. wp-bee.com . Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i don`t get your idea
but at all
css code have 3 ways

first be inside html page like this

```
<head>
<title>hello</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
background-color: #CC0000;
}
</style>
</head>
```

second have page and include it with html page like this
the page save like name "sheet.css"
and include it before close head like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sheet.css" media="screen"/>
```

the last way from js page like this

```
$("body").css("background-color","#CC0000");
```

Comment: Please refer this page. http://www.financialcontent.com/free-stock-market-widgets/market-snapshot.php . I am also creating a stock market widget only. My output is a simple HTML table. So, I need to style the  TH, TD and other tags with differnt colors (red or green) based on the  price fluctuation. Thanks!

Comment: I like this answer as well. Make a CSS file with your styles, attach it to the DOM tree (`<link rel="stylesheet" ... />`), and then use css classes to style your HTML table. You can do all these things with HTML or javascript. If you don't want to attach a stylesheet, then you can put your CSS in a HTML `<style>` tag like they do in that website.

Comment: I added my code in the question now. It may give you better idea of..what i am into?