# Coding inline CSS in JSON format

Tags: json

How to code the following inline css in JSON? I need to code as like a simple string.

```
<p style="color:sienna;margin-left:20px">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Looks like I need to add escape characters. But, tried few. But still got error in http://www.jslint.com/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean CSS in JSON? What are u trying to achieve?

Comment: Here is my original post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679014/adding-css-to-a-javascript-widget . I have decided to code inline CSS to format the widget. So, I like to translate the above inline css  as like this one colspan=\"3\" scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded-q6\" . I build the entire HTML table in the PHP and return the JSON and it goes directly in to the browser. No parsing of JSON needed anywhere. So, as long as i code the inline CSS as a valid JSON string, I should be good.

Comment: So when put the above code in JSLINT i got the following error Expected '(end)' and instead saw '</'. I tried to add escape characters here and there...didn't work. the '<' is giving the issue.

Comment: Please don't mix HTML and JSON, they are different entities meant for different things. Why do u need to output JSON directly to the browser as Html?

Comment: Looks @  my test site. http://wp-bee.com/ You can see at the right hand side "Stocks Under Accumulation" widget. It's a html table return from JS-> JS AJAX -> PHP/JSON . Now, I need to add the css to style the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this format.

Actually, you have to use a single (') quote instead of a double (") quote in style.

```
<p style='color:sienna;margin-left:20px'>Hello! world</p> </br>
```

Hopefully, it will work.

Comment: I was having the same issue and this worked for me. I was adding a inline style to post a ticket using FreshDesk API. The ticket was created when a server went down and would alert support team when that happens.